# Using a variable as a filter criteria in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, filter, criteria

I'm trying to filter before a date using VBA, I recorded a macro as a base to add variables into.

`SDatesel` is a variable containing a concatenation of `"<"` & sDate
`SDate` is the start date defined by the user in sell AC of the `"Base Sheet"` tab

```
sDate = Worksheets("Base Sheet".Range("A2")
```

The strings are fine as in debug mode they display properly

It's falling over at the line

```
Inspections.Range("A:S").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criertia1= _

   sDateSel, Operator:=xlAnd

Dim sDate As Date
Dim eDate As Date

sDate = Worksheets("Base Sheet").Range("A2")
eDate = Worksheets("Base Sheet").Range("C2")

Dim sDateSel As String
Dim eDateSel As String
'Dim Qot As String

sDateSel = "<" & sDate
eDateSel = ">" & eDate

Inspections.Range("$A:$S").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
    sDateSel, Operator:=xlAnd
Rows("2:2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("C1").Select
Inspections.Range("$A:$S").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
    eDateSel, Operator:=xlAnd
Rows("2:2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Selection.AutoFilter
```

The error I'm getting is 424 - Object Required

I believe this is due to the use of variables as this works when either sDateSel or eDateSel at raw figures like `"<20/05/2019"`

Comment: What is `Inspections`?

Comment: A named sheet within the workbook......I'm guessing my syntax trips over there rather than an issue with the variable?

Comment: Just trying to rule possible causes out. The line works with `Inspections` but replacing `sDateSel` with `<20/05/2019`?

Comment: Try Changing `sDateSel = "<" & sDate` this to `sDateSel = "<" & Format(sDate,"dd/mm/yyyy")` .... As usually date in VBA is `mm/dd/yyyy`  ..... and Similarly the others.